When did Lubavitch begin eating only Lubavitch meat?
Many Lubavitchers today only eat meat slaughtered from another Lubavitcher. Does anyone know when this came about? For of course one must eat meat from one that is yirei shamayim, for a shochet is not merely just one who slaughters meat, rather strongly G-d fearing, as has been explained by previous ChaBaD Rebbes.
Does anyone know when Lubavitchers dafka only began eating Lubavitcher meat, including to the point not eating other meat if faced with such? Additionally, if the Rebbe zt"l validated other meats that are shechted by a yirei Shamayim, why do some reject such meat even when shown they are yirei Shamayim?

https://anash.org/lubavitcher-shechita/

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66359/6592
